# Android Studio: Can't set Gradle/Gradle Plugin Version?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to set Gradle and Gradle plugin version for my project in Android Studio, but all I see in Project Structure>Project is this:
[image]

I was expecting to see something like this:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running? Your tag is for 2.2, which is positively ancient.

Comment: Should be 4.2, my bad